# How to check the proper order of the clauses in a given sql query using regexp in java?

Tags: java, mysql, regex, string

As of now i just want to check whether the order of the clauses - select, from, where, order by. are correct in a query.
I tried this:

```
String pattern1 = "select";
String pattern2 =  "from";
String pattern3 = "(where\\s*(.*?)|order by\\s*(.*?)|where\\s*(.*?)order by\\s*(.*?))";
String pattern4 = "(;|$)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern1 + "(.*?)" + pattern2 + "(.*?)" + pattern3 + pattern4);
```

But still this matches an incorrect query like this:

```
select * from student order by marks where id<8;
```

I need to do it manually without using any external libraries.

Comment: This is _a lot_ more complicated than it sounds. I'm not even sure a regex can be used to parse a SQL query (think about subquery, `with` clause, `group by`...)

Comment: You need a tempered greedy token based regex.

Comment: Similiar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5070879/. Regex is not proper tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

SQL allows arbitrary naming of columns, so simple string searches are not going to be sufficient. Although not recommended, you can write a query such as this:

```
select 1 as `order`, 2 as `select`, 3 as `limit`
```

That is, simple string searches are not sufficient.

And, even worse, SQL supports subqueries.  The following is a reasonable example:

```
select (select col
        from t
        where . . .
        group by x
        order by count(*) desc
        limit 1
       ) col, . . .
from tt
order by 2;
```

In other words, it is a recursive grammar.

Comment: Comments `--` and `/**/` can complicate it even more.